# get_template_directory_uri() providing wrong path for img

Tags: php, permalinks, links

I've recently uploaded my wordpress project to my web hosting and images arent showing properly, the source for the images is adding a %20 suffix to my theme directory.

this is the error thats thrown in console

```
   GET http://sixten.thrillcode.com/wp-content/themes/shapely%20/img/slideshow1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

it should be

```
    http://sixten.thrillcode.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/img/slideshow1.jpg
```

in my php file it is written as

```
   <img class="mobile-image-full" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slideshow1.jpg"> </img>
```

I cannot figure out what the issue is, if anyone could help i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a space after the word "shapely". You must remove that, spaces and special characters are encoded when used in URL's.
Most probably this space is in the directory name, rename it and it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is the encoded equivalent for space character. Since the URLs can not contain any spaces, they are converted to + or `%20`. So,

1. There is possibly either a space in your theme's folder name.
2. There is a space between your characters in the image src.